# Error on making a get request to a feature layer?

Tags: python, api, request

I am trying to query a feature layer from a script using the arcgis api for python:

```py
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
lomr = FeatureLayer("https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/1")
```

However, when I make a call to view properties, or actually perform a query:

```py
lomr.properties.extent
lomr.query(where="DFIRM_ID = '08013C'",outSR=2876,outFields='*')
```

I get the following error (after quite a long traceback):

```py
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

I even get a similar error if I try pasting [this query url](https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/1/query?where=DFIRM_ID+%3D+%2708013C%27&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=2876&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=html) through the requests library:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("https://hazards.fema.gov/gis/nfhl/rest/services/public/NFHL/MapServer/1/query?where=DFIRM_ID+%3D+%2708013C%27&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=2876&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=html")
```

This seems like a problem on FEMA's side, as I'm guessing "peer" means the server of the client-server request. How do I avoid this error and actually get a successful get request?

**[EDIT 1]** - I thought this could potentially be a problem with using jupyter notebooks, but I tried this same process through python in the terminal and got the same error.

**[EDIT 2]** - I have also tried this through a virtual environment set up with pipenv with the same results. I've tried this on macOS and my Windows at work. Here are the versions of everything I'm working with:

pipenv - 2018.11.26
python - 3.7.4
jupyter notebook - 6.0.1
arcgis - 1.6.2

Comment: Have a look here, might help: https://community.esri.com/thread/219658-using-the-arcgis-api-for-python-with-a-rest-service

Comment: @umbe1987 I tried the suggestion listed (using arcgis.mapping) to no avail. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I just tested your code and it is working from my side (it is returning 17 features) (tested with Jupyer notebook, arcgis API version 1.6.2).

Comment: Huh, this is boggling my mind @umbe1987. I even tried setting up a virtual environment, installing the same version of arcigs API that you did, and still no luck. I guess there must be something about my configuration...? How did you initially install the arcgis API? I'm pretty sure I did ```conda install -c esri arcgis```. And for the virtualenv I just did ```pipenv install arcgis```.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your antivirus? I remember having issues with COMODO. I have ArcGIS Pro 2.4, which comes with the conda console. I cloned the default conda env of ArcGIS Pro and upgraded arcgis package with `conda upgrade -c esri arcgis`.

Comment: @umbe1987 I don't think that's the issue, as I've tried this on my mac and work PC. Perhaps it's how I'm setting up my testing environment. Do you have a link to best practices on cloning the Pro conda environment?

Comment: @umbe1987 I got it to run successfully by cloning the conda env that ships with Pro, which means the error must be occurring because of how I initialized my environment with pipenv. I'd still like to solve the underlying issue so people trying to access the api without access to a Pro conda env could do what they need.